# Is it possible to program a stepwise continuos probability distribution via the commons-math3 package or directly in AnyLogic?

Tags: anylogic, probability-density, probability-distribution

The searched probability distribution assigns probabilities to certain intervals, so that the distribution looks like a staircase.
I want to use this probability distribution in AnyLogic and  did not find a adequate probability distribution neither in the AnyLogic library nor in the apache.commons.math3.package.

Attention: the distribution is NOT a discrete distribution but based on intervals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your custom distribution. I do it as follows..my input:

[image]

My custom distribution:
[image]